# Vercel/Netlify serverless functions lifecycle. Can code run after response?

Tags: serverless, netlify, vercel

I have a serverless function that fetches data from the github api and saves it to the filesystem to cache it.

My current code looks like this

```
export async function cachedFetch(url: string, options: RequestInit, cacheKey: string){
    let file = Path.join(tmpPath,cacheKey+".cache");

    function obtainAndCache(){
        return fetch(url, options).then(async r=>{
            let text = await r.text();
            writeFile(file,text).catch(console.error); // note: don't await the file write
            return text;
        })
    }

    if (existsSync(file)){
        let stat = await lstat(file);
        let timeOfLastFetch = stat.mtime.valueOf();
        let time = Date.now();
        let timeSinceLastFetch = time - timeOfLastFetch;
        if (timeSinceLastFetch >= MINUTE){
            obtainAndCache().catch(console.error); // note: don't await the request
        }
        let text = String(await readFile(file));
        return text;
    } else {
        return obtainAndCache();
    }
}
```

What my program flow should look like:

check cache (cache does not contain the resource) -> start fetch -> fetch completes -> start writing resource to the file -> resolve with fetched resource -> done writing to the file

check cache (cache contains resource) -> start fetch -> resolve with cached resource -> respond to the client with the cached resource -> fetch completes -> start writing resource to the file -> done writing to the file

As you can see in both cases I still have code running after the server responds to the client.

So my questions are:

1. After sending the response does my code still execute or is the process killed?
2. Are the files saved to tmp retaind between **warm started** function invocations? (Obviously if the function is cold started it will not have data from previous invocations)

I'm looking for vercel and netlify specific answers.

Currently I'm using netlify, but I'm willing to switch to vercel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure as I'm not familiar with what netlify expects, but if your only way to interact with the tool that sent you the request is via the response to that request, then this is a good use case for step functions.

Once your labda returns - sending a response to netlify - you want to summon a new lambda to take care of the file writing.